# PySpark: Subtract Dataframe Ignoring Some Columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to perform subtract between 2 dataframes in pyspark. Challenge is that I have to ignore some columns while subtracting dataframe. But end dataframe should have all the columns, including ignored columns.

Here is an example:

```
userLeft = sc.parallelize([
    Row(id=u'1', 
        first_name=u'Steve', 
        last_name=u'Kent', 
        email=u's.kent@email.com',
        date1=u'2017-02-08'),
    Row(id=u'2', 
        first_name=u'Margaret', 
        last_name=u'Peace', 
        email=u'marge.peace@email.com',
        date1=u'2017-02-09'),
    Row(id=u'3', 
        first_name=None, 
        last_name=u'hh', 
        email=u'marge.hh@email.com',
        date1=u'2017-02-10')
]).toDF()

userRight = sc.parallelize([
    Row(id=u'2', 
        first_name=u'Margaret', 
        last_name=u'Peace', 
        email=u'marge.peace@email.com',
        date1=u'2017-02-11'),
    Row(id=u'3', 
        first_name=None, 
        last_name=u'hh', 
        email=u'marge.hh@email.com',
        date1=u'2017-02-12')
]).toDF()
```

Expected:

```
ActiveDF = userLeft.subtract(userRight) ||| Ignore "date1" column while subtracting.
```

End result should look something like this including "date1" column.

```
+----------+--------------------+----------+---+---------+
|     date1|               email|first_name| id|last_name|
+----------+--------------------+----------+---+---------+
|2017-02-08|    s.kent@email.com|     Steve|  1|     Kent|
+----------+--------------------+----------+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need `anti-join`:

```
userLeft.join(userRight, ["id"], "leftanti").show()
+----------+----------------+----------+---+---------+  
|     date1|           email|first_name| id|last_name|
+----------+----------------+----------+---+---------+
|2017-02-08|s.kent@email.com|     Steve|  1|     Kent|
+----------+----------------+----------+---+---------+
```

Comment: "leftanti" is not available in pyspark 1.6. I do not have any specific primary key for these dataframe. My dataframe gets generated on run time. So, I am not aware of it's column details. But I always know, which Columns I do not want to consider while joining.

Comment: One option is `userLeft.join(userRight, [col for col in userLeft.columns if col != 'date1'], "leftanti")` if you want to join on all columns except for `date1`, but this is not null safe, you might need to fill null value with an empty string before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `full join` and only keep `null` values:

```
userLeft.join(
    userRight, 
    [c for c in userLeft.columns if c != "date1"], 
    "full"
 ).filter(psf.isnull(userLeft.date1) | psf.isnull(userRight.date1)).show()

    +------------------+----------+---+---------+----------+----------+
    |             email|first_name| id|last_name|     date1|     date1|
    +------------------+----------+---+---------+----------+----------+
    |marge.hh@email.com|      null|  3|       hh|2017-02-10|      null|
    |marge.hh@email.com|      null|  3|       hh|      null|2017-02-12|
    |  s.kent@email.com|     Steve|  1|     Kent|2017-02-08|      null|
    +------------------+----------+---+---------+----------+----------+
```

If you want to use joins, whether it's `leftanti` or `full` you'll need to find default values for your `null` in the joining columns (I think we discussed it in a previous thread).

You can also just `drop` the column that bothers you `subtract` and `join`:

```
df = userLeft.drop("date1").subtract(userRight.drop("date1"))
userLeft.join(df, df.columns).show()

    +----------------+----------+---+---------+----------+
    |           email|first_name| id|last_name|     date1|
    +----------------+----------+---+---------+----------+
    |s.kent@email.com|     Steve|  1|     Kent|2017-02-08|
    +----------------+----------+---+---------+----------+
```

Comment: It is a production data. I cannot touch NULLs and assign it a default value.